# What is the output of "du" command during a long copy?

Tags: process, disk-usage, cp

Recently, I launched the `cp` command to create a backup of a big directory. So, I used a command like this:

```
cp -rv big_directory new_location
```

Because the files are big, it took a long time to execute this command, and I also wanted to look at the progress of the copy. So I also used the `du` command in another terminal, like this:

```
du -sh new_location/*
```

But this command also takes a long time to be executed. Specially if there are big files in this directory.

Suppose that the `cp` command takes 10 minutes to be executed. If I launch the command `du` 1 minute after having launched the `cp` command, and supposing that `du` takes 1 minute to be executed, I would like to know if I can trust the output of `du`?

Does it give me a reliable output of the situation when `du` was launched (t=1min), or does it give me an output of the situation at the end of `du` execution time (t=2min)? Obviously the size of the directory `new_location` have changed between the start and the end of `du` command because of the copy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@derobert explained how `du` operates.

He didn't mention that unless you have an absolutely huge number of small files / directories (so the metadata takes a huge amount of memory), then running `du` again right away usually produces a result much more quickly.

One large file doesn't make `du` slow, but copying it is more likely to push directory caches out of memory.  ([desktop responsiveness can be improved](https://rudd-o.com/linux-and-free-software/tales-from-responsivenessland-why-linux-feels-slow-and-how-to-fix-that) by setting `vm.swappiness=10`, and prioritizing metadata over data with `vm.vfs_cache_pressure=60` sysctl settings (put them in `/etc/sysctl.d/99-local`.)

When multiple processes are accessing the filesystem at the same time, every system call gets information that's a snapshot of the state when it was run.  For example, a process might check if a file existed, then try to open it, only to find out that it wasn't there anymore.  Because another process had renamed/removed it during that interval between checks.  (When this causes a problem / is the source of a bug, it's called a race condition.)

If the order of `du`'s directory traversal is the same as the order that `cp` chose, then `du` won't get to the still-being-modified directory until near the end of its run-time, and thus won't have missed much by the time it finishes.  OTOH, if `du` sums the directory where `cp` is putting new files first, and then takes another minute to sum the rest, the result will be stale.

Comment: I'm really interested to know how multiple processes are managed by Linux. Assume that I'm launching the `du` command firstly, and then, I want to remove this files with `rm`. If we suppose that `rm` goes fast, are you saying me that because `du` accesses to information thanks a snapshot, the result of `du` would be the same if I hadn't launched the `rm` command ? 
Tell me if I'm unclear.

Comment: @Nairolf21: nothing snapshots anything.  If `rm` happens to remove anything `du` hasn't seen yet, the output of `du` won't include it.  If not, it won't.  It all depends on which order the two commands traverse the directory tree.  Usually that's in the order of results returned by `readdir`.  On a multi-CPU system, `du` and `rm` can both be doing stuff at the same time, rather than trading 10ms timeslices.  Things to google if you're still confused: locking, concurrency, race conditions.

Answer (score 2):

`du` works by scanning through the directory recursively, counting up the size of all the files & directories. Something like:

1. start with the first directory given on the command line.
2. `stat` the directory to determine its size, add that to the total
3. read the first entry (file or subdirectory name) from the directory
4. if it's a file, `stat` it and add it to the total
5. if it's a directory (other than `.` and `..`, of course), do steps 2–7 for the subdirectory
6. if there is another entry, read it and go back to 4 [you might wonder: what happens if another entry is added by `cp` while `du` is scanning through a single directory? The [standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/readdir.html) says it may or may not show up—it's unspecified.]
7. print out the directory size

If the directories and files are changing as `du` does all that (as they are in your case) then the size it gives isn't the one from the beginning or the end, it's something in between—but not completely. Probably close enough though, at least with `cp`.

To get progress indicators, in addition to @roaima's `rsync` suggestion, there is `cp -v`, `gcp` (found via a quick search), and complicated things like `(cd /src && tar c .) | pv -pterb -s $(du -sb /src) | (cd /dst && tar x)`.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation of the process of `du`. I didn't know this tools `gcp` and `pv`. That looks nice.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `rsync` installed you can watch the copy progress like this

```
rsync -vP big_directory new_location
```

If you wanted to preserve permissions, timestamps, ownerships, etc. you would add the `-a` flag to `rsync` or the `-p` flag to `cp`.

---

This answer sidesteps the use of `du` on the assumption that you actually wanted to watch the progress of the copy rather than see an approximation to the disk space used.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. rsync seems to a be a useful tool. I could use it in the future. However, even if my first motivation was to watch the progress of the copy, it's not the subject of this question.
I am more interested by knowing how Linux deals with multiple processes when they target same files. My question was with`du` and `cp` commands. But it could also be with `cp -r dir1 dir2` and `rm -r dir2`. Or also `cp -r dir1 dir2` and `cp -r dir2 dir3`.